# How to recover data back from SSTables to Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, apt, data-recovery

I tried to reinstall Cassandra, now data missing! 
I found SSTables still remains and consumes lots of space in disk.

what I have done

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove cassandra
sudo apt-get install dsc20
```

How can I get the data back into cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of hacky (the tool isn't being used as intended) but you could use sstable2json to export the data from the old sstables into json, and then re-import it back to your new C* install. To do this you must:

1. Export the data from the old sstables using [sstable2json](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/sstable2json)
2. Re-create the CF that you previously had (same structure)
3. Flush the newly created identical cf (`./nodetool flush`)
4. Stop cassandra
5. Import the json you exported previously into the newly created sstables using json2sstable.

This is hacky because json2sstable and sstable2json are debug tools rather than export/import tools.